# Azure file storage - Upload file in nested directories

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage-files

I want to upload files but in a nested folder environment. I have no problem to create a directory and upload a file but when using nested directories I got a storage exception when trying to create folders.  Here is a code example.

```
   CloudFileDirectory rootDirectory = FileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
   if (rootDirectory.Exists())
   {
       cloudFileDirectory = rootDirectory.GetDirectoryReference("Folder/SubFolder"); 

        cloudFileDirectory.CreateIfNotExists(); //Exception occur

        var file = cloudFileDirectory.GetFileReference("File.txt");
   }
```

Do I have to create a method that create directory for directory or is there a more simple solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I have to create a method that create directory for directory or is
>   there a more simple solution?

Yes, you would need to do that. You can't specify a folder structure and have SDK take care of it for you. Please take a look at sample code below for one approach.

```
    static void NestedDirectoriesTest()
    {
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
        var client = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
        var share = client.GetShareReference("temp2");
        share.CreateIfNotExists();
        var cloudFileDirectory = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
        var nestedFolderStructure = "Folder/SubFolder";
        var delimiter = new char[] { '/' }; 
        var nestedFolderArray = nestedFolderStructure.Split(delimiter);
        for (var i=0; i<nestedFolderArray.Length; i++)
        {
            cloudFileDirectory = cloudFileDirectory.GetDirectoryReference(nestedFolderArray[i]);
            cloudFileDirectory.CreateIfNotExists();
            Console.WriteLine(cloudFileDirectory.Name + " created...");
        }
    }
```